# Question mark clicked on Android keyboard

Tags: android

I'm passing information about keys pressed on Android keyboard in my application using method

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
```

in my activity. Later on I'm comparing keyCode with KeyEvent constants. Everything works fine, except for the question mark ('?'). I've tried using

```
if (event.isShiftPressed() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SLASH)
```

because I've found such a solution in the Internet, but it does not work. How can I check if the question mark button was clicked on the keyboard?

EDIT: The code above does work. Thanks, Virat Singh!

Comment: What you are doing `if (event.isShiftPressed() && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SLASH)` should work... Can you clarify what you mean by "later on [you are] comparing keyCode with KeyEvent constants"? It's possible that the `event` has a different value for `isShiftPressed()`.

Comment: Okay, sorry, it does work. I made a mistake later with reading the signal and thought that this piece of code doesn't work, but it actually does. Thank you for pointing out that it should work, it made me check my code again and really helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
char c = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
```

Try this method, it will easily convert the character.